# UITableView vs UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have two components.
Both of them need to be horizontally scrollable.
What they will contain is just what you see.

First Component:
A rounded image and some text on hover. Maybe a touch hold event will be added later thats all. Nothing more complex than that.

Second Component:
A horizontal form with 5 fields.

I'm really new to Swift and iOS and I want to know what is the best technique to achieve this.

I don't want to get into the most complex one. I want to use something that does the job.

I have done some research and I found that there are three ways of doing this.

`UITableView` vs `UICollectionView`

Which one should I use for this purpose?

Note: **The two components are NOT related to each other at all**

[image]

Comment: UICollectionView is suitable for this because for customisation  for this problem it will be the better as compare to other options

Comment: I think `UITableView` with customised cell having `UICollectionView` in it will be a better approach

Comment: Sorry can you explain a little more in detail this UITableView with customised cell having UICollectionView? @Amit

What about UIScrollView?

Comment: you can use UICollectionView with Horizontal Scroll.

Comment: Please go through this blog: https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/.